# Importance of undergraduate honors thesis vs. research published in undergraduate research journal, for graduate schools in the United States?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, research-undergraduate, psychology

I have the option of graduating from my university (U.S.) a semester early. If I do so, I would not be able to complete my honors thesis and have it approved by the honors committee of my university. However, I would still complete the same research project, write up the manuscript, and probably submit it to my university's undergraduate research journal.

For admission to psychology PhD programs in the United States, how important is the actual "honors thesis" component?

Comment: What is your field of study?  See [Academia varies](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1212/11365)

Comment: @ff524 Psychology

Comment: The answer to your question probably varies not only by field but by the particular people who happen to be on the admissions committee. In general, I'd expect the difference between "undergraduate honors thesis" and "published in my university's undergraduate research journal" to be rather small compared to what the letters of recommendation say about this research.